# Character encoding errors with .NET Core on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, character-encoding, .net-core, .net-core-2.1

This has been driving me batty for days, and I've finally got it down to a simple, reproducible issue.

I have a NUnit test project, which is .NET Core 2.1. It references a library (let's call it "Core") which is .NET Standard 2.0.

In my test project:

```
[TestCase(true, false)]
[TestCase(false, false)]
[TestCase(false, true)]
public void ShouldStartWith(bool useInternal, bool passStartsWith)
{
    var result = useInternal ? StartsWithQ("¿Que?") : StringUtilities.StartsWithQ("¿Que?", passStartsWith ? "¿" : null);
    result.ShouldBeTrue();
}

public static bool StartsWithQ(string s)
{
    return _q.Any(q => s.StartsWith(q, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

and in the `Core` project in the `StringUtilities` class:

```
public static bool StartsWithQ(string s, string startsWith = null)
{
    return startsWith == null
        ? _q.Any(q => s.StartsWith(q, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        : s.StartsWith(startsWith, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Both classes have defined a list of special characters:

```
private static readonly List<string> _q = new List<string>
{
    "¡",
    "¿"
};
```

In a Windows environment, all test cases pass. But when the same tests run in the Linux environment, the test case `ShouldStartWith(False,False)` fails!

That means that when everything is running in the test project, the string comparison works correctly, and even if you pass the special characters to the `StringUtilities` method, the comparison works. But when you compare to a string that was compiled in the Core project, the special characters are no longer equivalent!

Anyone know why this is? Is this a .NET bug? How to work around it?

Comment: What does `file` show as the file type for both the unit test and the implementation on Linux? On my machine, it reports as `Program.cs: C++ source, UTF-8 Unicode text` and the test passes.

Comment: @omajid I don't understand the question. Can you please spell out how to do the test you suggested?

Comment: As with any text file, you have to correctly communicate the character encoding to programs that read it. What is the encoding of your source files and what are you telling the compiler? UTF-8 would be a good plan.  (`file` is a program that guesses the encoding. It may or may not be useful in showing you that a file doesn't have the encoding that you think it does. Some interpretation is required.)

Comment: @omajid `Test.dll: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows` `Core.dll: PE32 executable (DLL) (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows`

Comment: @TomBlodget see above comment

Comment: Can you please run file on the source files? All the files containing the upside-down question mark. Another thing to consider: can you use the unicode escape code (`\udddd`) for these non-ascii characters? Does that help the test results?

Comment: The discussion was continued on github (but no definite answer): https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/31278

Answer (score 1):

The encodings of your source files most likely don't match each other and/or not the compiler settings.

Example:

The sourcefile containing `public void ShouldStartWith(bool useInternal, bool passStartsWith)` may be encoded using utf-8 while the source file with the list is encoded in Latin-1 (or something like that).

When we play this through:

- The utf-8 representation of `¿` would be: `0xC2 0xBF`.
- The Latin-1 representation of `¿` would be: `0xBF`.

Thus, when the compiler interprets your source files as Latin-1, then he will read 2 bytes in the case of the utf-8 saved file (and according to Latin-1 also 2 chars) and therefore fails to match the strings.

As already stated in the comments: The best way to overcome this is to encode the source files in the encoding the compiler awaits.

Another way to exclude the operating system as error source: Copy the compiled project (the dll's - don't recompile the source on the other operating system) from one operating system to the other and execute the code. You should see the same behaviour on both operating systems with the same binary compiler output.

Comment: .Net uses UTF-16 to represent characters and strings. Also see [Character Encoding in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding) on MSDN. If UTF-8 or Latin-1 is being used without an explicit conversion then things are sideways.

Comment: You confuse the encoding in source files and the encoding used at runtime.