# Azure Pipeline - wrong characters returned as a result of Assert

Tags: localization, azure-devops, xunit

Can't figure out how to solve my issue with international (Russian, in this case) characters, returned from xUnit-tests project in my solution (ASP.NET Core 2, a test project in the solution).

Question is : **How to make them readable?**

[image: wrong characters]

I'm using build-machine based on Ubuntu 16.04, above you may see the result of Assert that fail. There are 2 strings that should be compared and I can't even understand what strings do i have there. So what I want is to see real text instead of these ��� .

I suppose that also it could be a reason of a test fail as locally, on my laptop everything is fine and I don't have the failed test. But there I can see that some additional character - what is that?  Can't understand...

Here is a section that runs tests on Azure Pipeline (from azure-pipelines.yml)^

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test $(buildConfiguration)'
  name: testsRun
  continueOnError: true
  inputs:
    command: test    
    projects: '*Test.*/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"Code coverage" --no-build --no-restore'
    testRunTitle: 'run all tests'
    publishTestResults: true
```

Thanks in advance!

PS - It was a long time ago when I asked a question here last time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May i know following questions?

1. Which encoding of the *.cs file in test project did you use? You can use an editor tool to view the encoding format. It should be UTF-8. This topic may be helpful for you.

[Character encoding errors with .NET Core on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51364469/character-encoding-errors-with-net-core-on-linux)

2. Is agent pool (Ubuntu 16.04) you run the pipeline a local ubuntu machine or vm, or the host is selected from the Agent Pool list in Azure DevOps? If it is local machine or VM, you need to check if the OS supports Russian laguage.

I can not reproduce this issue. The text displays as readable. The test project was created by VS 2017. And the agent pool is Hosted Ubuntu 1604 listed in DevOps.

```
        Assert.Equal("здравствуй, мир!", "здравствуй, мир11!");
```

Please see the result.[Azure PipeLine Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9niDl.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot! After I saved CS file in UTF8 encoding I got my tests passed.